# How to access Fields in zap Hooks?

Tags: go, logging, go-zap

How can I access the full information about the logging event in uber-zap's hooks?

For example, I am trying to add a `zapcore.Field` to the logging event, but it does not show up in the `zapcore.Entry`.

If it is not possible, can I at least have the fully-formatted string somehow? The goal is to send an email/automated message/Sentry/etc in case of errors.

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew"
    "go.uber.org/zap"
    "go.uber.org/zap/zapcore"
)

func main() {
    prodLogger, err := zap.NewProduction(zap.Hooks(func(entry zapcore.Entry) error {
        if entry.Level == zapcore.ErrorLevel {
            spew.Dump(entry) // fancy console printer
        }

        return nil
    }))

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    prodLogger.
        Named("logger_name").
        Error("something happened", zap.String("foo", "bar"))
}
```

Output - no traces of `foo` or `bar`:

```
{"level":"error","ts":1640722252.899601,"logger":"logger_name","caller":"awesomep2/main.go:23","msg":"something happened","foo":"bar","stacktrace":"main.main\n\t/Users/xxx/GitHub/awesomep2/main.go:23\nruntime.main\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:255"}
(zapcore.Entry) {
 Level: (zapcore.Level) error,
 Time: (time.Time) 2021-12-28 13:10:52.899601 -0700 MST m=+0.000629089,
 LoggerName: (string) (len=11) "logger_name",
 Message: (string) (len=18) "something happened",
 Caller: (zapcore.EntryCaller) /Users/xxx/GitHub/awesomep2/main.go:23,
 Stack: (string) (len=103) "main.main\n\t/Users/xxx/GitHub/awesomep2/main.go:23\nruntime.main\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:255"
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fields are not available in Zap hooks. The docs of [`zap.Hooks`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.uber.org/zap#Hooks) say this explicitly:

> [...] Hooks are useful for simple side effects, like capturing metrics for the number of emitted logs. More complex side effects, **including anything that requires access to the Entry's structured fields**, should be implemented as a zapcore.Core instead. [...]

So to dump logs with go-spew, you need a custom core. You have two main options.

#### Custom core with custom encoder

This has the advantage of allowing more customization.

The entry's fields are available in `zapcore.Encoder.EncodeEntry`. The strategy is, as usual, to embed a `zapcore.Encoder` into your struct and reimplement `EncodeEntry`:

```
type spewDumpEncoder struct {
    zapcore.Encoder
}

func (e *spewDumpEncoder) EncodeEntry(entry zapcore.Entry, fields []zapcore.Field) (*buffer.Buffer, error) {
    if entry.Level == zapcore.ErrorLevel {
        spew.Dump(entry, fields)
    }
    return e.Encoder.EncodeEntry(entry, fields)
}
```

Remember to implement `Clone()` as well, if you plan to use structured logging.

#### Custom core with `Write`

This has the advantage of allowing simpler initialization.

Similarly to the first option, `zapcore.Core` is also an interface, so you can implement it by embedding in your struct, and reimplement only `Write`:

```
type MyCore struct {
    zapcore.Core
}

func (c *MyCore) Check(entry zapcore.Entry, checked *zapcore.CheckedEntry) *zapcore.CheckedEntry {
    if c.Enabled(entry.Level) {
        return checked.AddCore(entry, c)
    }
    return checked
}

func (c *MyCore) Write(entry zapcore.Entry, fields []zapcore.Field) error {
    if entry.Level == zapcore.ErrorLevel {
        spew.Dump(entry, fields)
    }
    return c.Core.Write(entry, fields)
}
```

and instantiate it by taking the existing core from a default zap logger:

```
    l, _ := zap.NewProduction()
    logger := zap.New(&MyCore{Core: l.Core()})
```